# Add entries from a CSV into different arrays on awk and print them

Tags: awk

I am making a .awk script and am taking in a .csv file containing product prices. The input file is:

```
Product,Price
EG412,25
EG411,15
EG516,55
EG517,60
LG210,10
LG180,5
HG915,95
```

I have already gotten an average through adding the second column and dividing by NR - 1, but now I am supposed to add products into arrays based upon if they are above or below the average price point. The issue I am running into is that my arrays are not printing and are also adding the top column of the csv containing "Product,Price". The code I have is:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
    sum=0
    avg=0
    high=0
    low=0
}
{
    sum+=$2
    total=NR-1
}
{
    avg=sum/total
}
{
    if ($2 > avg && NR > 1) {
        expensive[high] = $1
        high++
    } else if ($2 < avg && NR > 1) {
        cheap[low] = $1
        low++
    }
}
{
    for (i in expensive) {
        print i
        i++
    }
}
END{
    printf "Average Price: ""%.2\n", avg
}
```

I feel like I am doing this in an incredibly convoluted way, but I can't figure out how to get this to work. When I run it this way to test the array for only high value products, the result it returns is:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
Average Price: 37.86
```

I would appreciate any help resolving this issue.

Comment: You don't need all the sections, as you have no conditions on any of them. So just 1 is needed. You can also do something like `entry[i++]=..`.   This should help you reduce it somewhat.

Comment: When doing this my code for adding variables into the array is the same except for under the if and else if statements it has changed to: ' expensive[i++] = $1 ' but it still giving me numbers back instead of the product numbers.

Comment: Remember every *Rule* (`{ ... }`) is applied to every *Record* (line) in the order they are written. You can't have the average of all prices before all records have been scanned at least once. Your options are to scan the file twice (once for average, then a 2nd time to choose the products) or you can save the records in an array and use the `END` rule to compute the average and then loop over your array selecting products (single-pass preferred)

Comment: `for ( i in array )` sets `i` to every index into `array`, so you want to print `array[i]`

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result

Comment: if a product's price is *equal* to the average, which category (`cheap` vs `expensive`) should this item be placed in?

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2-pass approach, first to calculate the average and then to determine which values are above/below the average:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
FNR == 1 {
    next
}
NR == FNR {
    tot += $2
    ave = tot / (NR-1)
    next
}
{
    if ( $2 < ave ) {
        cheap[$1]
    }
    else if ( $2 > ave ) {
        expensive[$1]
    }
}
END {
    print "Average:", ave+0

    print "\nCheap:"
    for ( product in cheap ) {
        print product
    }

    print "\nExpensive:"
    for ( product in expensive ) {
        print product
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
Average: 37.8571

Cheap:
LG180
LG210
EG411
EG412

Expensive:
EG516
EG517
HG915
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the average before hand, then pass it into your script, something like this should work:

*calc.awk*

```
# Arrays are 1-indexed
BEGIN { low = high = 1 }

NR == 1 { next }

$2  < avg { cheap[low++]      = $2 }
$2 >= avg { expensive[high++] = $2 }

END {
  printf "Average: %.2f\n", avg
  printf "Cheap:"
  for (i in cheap)
    printf " %d", cheap[i]
  printf "\nHigh:"
  for (i in expensive)
    printf " %d", expensive[i]
  printf "\n"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -v avg=37.8571 -F, -f calc.awk infile.csv
```

Output:

```
Average: 37.86
Cheap: 25 15 10 5
High: 55 60 95
```